Monty Hall Coin Flip
Before each show, Monty secretly flips a coin with a probability p of Heads. If the coin lands Heads, Monty resolves to open a goat door (with equal probabilities if there is a choice). Otherwise, Monty resolves to open a random, unopened door with equal probabilities. The contestant knows p but does not know the outcome of the coin flip. When the show starts, the contestant chooses a door. Monty (who knows where the car is) then opens a door. If the car is revealed, the game is over; if a goat is shown, the contestant is offered the option of switching. Now, suppose it turns out that the contestant opens door 1, and then Monty opens door 2, revealing a goat. What is the contestant's probability of success if he or she switches to door 3?
This problem is not too hard to set up given the Bayes Theorem; however, I have a hard time considering which should be the pr conditional probabilities on the opening door two, given that the car is behind each door.
I am thinking of using something along the lines of:
$$
P(D_3 / M_2) = \frac{P(M_2/D_3)P(D_3)}{P(M_2)} \equiv \frac{P(M_2/D_3).P(D_3)}{P(M_2/D_1)P(D_1). P(M_2/D_2)P(D_2). P(M_2/D_3)P(D_3)}
$$
Of course, $P(D_i) = \dfrac{1}{3} \forall i \in [1,3]$. However, I'm not sure how to think of $P(M_2/D_i)$.
$P(M_2/D_1) = 1/2$, since you choose one to begin with, the coinflip outcome is irrelevant, and Monty will choose any of the other doors.
For $P(M_2/D_2)$, I am not sure how to think about the condition of choosing door 1 to begin with. If the coin flip lands on Tails then door two will be open, if the coin flip is Heads then it wont (as Monty should not open door 1 and door 2 has the goat). So $P(M_2/D_2) = p * 0 + (1-p) 1$.
For $P(M_2/D_3)$, I have the same issue. If the player chooses 1 in the beginning, then door 2 will be open only when the outcome is Heads. Thus $P(M_2/D_3) = p * 1 + (1-p) 0$.
Am I thinking of this correctly?

There are no unopened doors when it is time for Monty to open the first one, so I suppose when you wrote “unopened” you meant “not the one the contestant chose.” Is that what you meant?

It does not really matter which doors the contestant or Monty pick, except where the car is relative to those actions and how the coin flip determined Monty's decision.
Door 1 is whichever door the contestant picks, Door 2 is whichever door Monty opens, and Door 3 is the remaining door.
So: the relevant events are just:

$D$: The car is behind the contestant's pick (door 1).
$M$: The goat is behind Monty's pick (door 2).
$H$: Monty's choice was predetermined (Ie the coin flip showed Heads).


When the contestant picks door 1, the car is behind it with probability $1/3$. $$\mathsf P(D)=1/3$$
In case of $D$, obviously opening door 2 can only reveal a goat.  $$\mathsf P(M\mid D)=1$$
In the alternative case, Monty's choice to open door 2 was either predetermined by the goat being there, or made randomly between the two choices.  $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(H)&= p\\\mathsf P(M\mid H,D^\complement)&=1\\\mathsf P(M\mid H^\complement, D^\complement)&=1/2\\[1ex]\mathsf P(M\mid D^\complement)&=\mathsf P(H)\,\mathsf P(M\mid H, D^\complement)+\mathsf P(H^\complement)\,\mathsf P(M\mid H^\complement, D^\complement)\end{align}$$
You seek the probability that the car is not behind the contestants pick of door 1 given that opening door 2 revealed a goat.  So we use Bayes' Rule and the Law of Total Probability:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(D^\complement\mid M)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(D^\complement)\,\mathsf P(M\mid D^\complement)}{\mathsf P(D^\complement)\,\mathsf P(M\mid D^\complement)+\mathsf P(D)\,\mathsf P(M\mid D)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(D^\complement)\,\bigl(\mathsf P(H)\,\mathsf P(M\mid H, D^\complement)+\mathsf P(H^\complement)\,\mathsf P(M\mid H^\complement, D^\complement)\bigr)}{\mathsf P(D^\complement)\,\bigl(\mathsf P(H)\,\mathsf P(M\mid H, D^\complement)+\mathsf P(H^\complement)\,\mathsf P(M\mid H^\complement, D^\complement)\bigr)+\mathsf P(D)\,\mathsf P(M\mid D)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{(2/3)(p+(1-p)/2)}{(2/3)(p+(1-p)/2)+(1/3)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{p+1}{p+2}\end{align}$$
